# How Apache Flink deal with skewed data?

Tags: apache-flink

For example, I have a big stream of words and want to count each word. The problem is these words is skewed. It means that the frequency of some words would be very high, but that of most other words is low. In storm, we could use the following way to solve this issue. First do shuffle grouping on the stream, in each node count words local in a window time, at the end update counts to cumulative results. 
From my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446247/apache-flink-streaming-window-wordcount), I know that Flink only supports window on a keyed stream, otherwise the window operation will not be parallel.

My question is is there a good way to solve this kind of skewed data issue in Flink?

[image]

Comment: in Storm I used "Partial Key grouping" and it handles better data skew. https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Concepts.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre-aggregation is currently not natively supported by the DataStream API. In principle, it is possible to add a combiner-like feature for event-time windows. IMO, this would be a very valuable addition but hasn't been done yet.

However, you can implement this feature yourself. The DataStream API offers low-level operator interface which is similar to Storm Bolts. The interface is called `OneInputStreamOperator`. This operator type gives you full control. In fact, the built-in operators (such as Window operators) are also based on this class.

A `OneInputStreamOperator` can be applied like:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String,Integer> inStream = ...
DataStream<String> outStream = inStream
  .transform("my op", BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO, new MyOISO());
```

Comment: Thanks for help. One question about implement this feature by myself. As Flink only supports window on a keyed stream, otherwise the window operation will not be parallel. So the implementation couldn't be `stream.PreAggregation(reduce_fun).keyBy().window().reduce(reduce_fun)`. Because pre-aggregation should be in a window time.  As I understand, it should be `stream.PreAggregationWithWindow(reduce_fun).keyBy().reduce(reduce_fun)`. Then I need implement a window operator working on a nonkeyed stream. Am I right?

Comment: You can also implement approximate in-memory window logic in the pre-aggregator. For that you can have a look at / copy from Flink's regular window code. I know, this is not an easy thing to do, but should be possible. This would enable the second (final) window to run in parallel as well and is the cleaner solution, IMO.

Comment: One thing I am not clear with the cleaner solution you mentioned is after pre-aggregation, it seems that there is no need to have the second window anymore. If there is for some other reasons, yes, it is parallel.

Comment: You can do `stream.transform(new PreAgg()).keyBy().window().reduce()` as you proposed before. In this case, `PreAgg` should implement keyed windowing logic very similar to Flink's window implementation (with fixed-sized state and maybe LRU eviction). Since the input of `PreAgg` is not partitioned (no `keyBy`) the keys are randomly distributed without skew. After `PreAgg`, you need to partition by key and define a window to compute the final result, similar to a combiner in MapReduce.

Comment: @FabianHueske Is that implemented as of today? If not, is that on roadmap?